# Will EF7 support collection initializers?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, c#-6.0, collection-initializer

C# 6 introduced some cool additions to how objects and collections are initialized.

For example this code is valid in C#6:

```
void Main()
{
    var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var myClass = new MyClass
    {
        // IEnumerableExtensions.Add<T> is called.
        Items = { ints } 
    };

    Console.WriteLine(myClass.Items.Count());
}

class MyClass
{
    public ICollection<int> Items { get;} = new List<int>();    
}

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void Add<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var list = collection as List<T>;
        if (list != null)
        {
            list.AddRange(items);
            return;
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }       
    }
}
```

So now it's possible to write initialization expression for the objects with read-only collection properties.

And sometimes I need to tell EF how assemble the entity:

```
from name in names
join addr in infoSecEmailAddresses
    on name.LegalEntityIsn equals addr.LegalEntityIsn into addresses
where legalEntityIsns.Contains(name.LegalEntityIsn)
select new LegalEntitySideInfoSecParameters
{
    LegalEntityIsn = name.LegalEntityIsn,
    LegalEntityName = name.FullNameNominative,
    Emails =  addresses.Select(
        a => new Email
        {
            EmailAddress = a.Address,
            RecipientPriority = a.RecipientPriority
        }).ToList()
}
```

Here `Emails` property need to be writable. But with the upper code it would be possible to make it read-only and rewrite code like this:

```
Emails =  {
    addresses.Select(
        a => new Email
        {
            EmailAddress = a.Address,
            RecipientPriority = a.RecipientPriority
        })
}
```

Actually, this can be done by introducing DTO with anonymous type later converted on the client (`AsEnumerable()`) to the required entity. Nonetheless, I'd like to have that feature supported by EF7 itself.

Comment: You are mixing up different concepts. LINQ is a *query* language. A LINQ query should be translatable to the underlying provider's language, in this case SQL. There are no initializers in SQL.  In fact, your LINQ-to-EF statement won't even compile unless you've already loaded everything in memory and use LINQ to objects (eg due to a call to AsEnumerable()). You shouldn't *have* to assemble anything either - EF should be able to load related objects automatically as long as you *do* define the relations

Comment: Well, EF is not only about generating queries, but also about materialization. This question is about the second part. And yes, sometimes I need to assemble entity from joins and projections rather than using standard mappings.

Comment: At the moment EF is not capable of calling any user method during materialization. L2S was able to do that. The feature request is still open.